# exports return null before executing mongodb save when i call it from another controller?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach

I have to call one controller function from another, but other function is not returning a proper value.
I called a function from one controller in line 'a',line 'b' is another controller.but inside forEach loop when it comes to line 'c', its not executing inside code instead it return null before executing the code from line 'd'.

```
a. var invoiceItemResp = InvoiceItemController.createInvoiceItems(itemList, doc.id);

b. exports.createInvoiceItems = (itemList, invoiceId) => {
    var counter = 0;
    var success = false;
    itemList.forEach(element => {
        var invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            invoice_id: invoiceId,
            item: element.item,
            amount: element.amount
        });
c.        invoiceItem.save((err, doc) => {
d.            if(!err){
                ++counter;
                if(counter == itemList.length){
                    response = {
                        "message": "success"
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            }else{
                response = {
                    "message": "failed"
                }
                return response;
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your needs the loop to be async and wait for DB to write,

```
const invoiceItemResp = await InvoiceItemController.createInvoiceItems(itemList, doc.id);



exports.createInvoiceItems =  async (itemList, invoiceId) =>
{
    var counter = 0;
    var success = false;
    let resposneArray = [];
    let response= {};
    try
    {
        for (const element of itemList)
        {
            var invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                invoice_id: invoiceId,
                item: element.item,
                amount: element.amount
            });
            const err = await invoiceItem.save();
            if (!err)
            {
                ++counter;
                if (counter == itemList.length)
                {
                    response = {
                        "message": "success"
                    };
                    resposneArray.push(response);
                }
            } else
            {
                response = {
                    "message": "failed"
                };
                resposneArray.push(response)
            }
        });

        return  resposneArray;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

};
```

Comment: if we use await in line 1, we have to add async in that controller because await will not work without async, if i add async also, another problem is if i add await in line 1 it come out of second controller(from line 2) before executing invoice.save(), after executing remaining lines in controller 1, it will go back to controller 2 to execute invoiceItem.save(), how it is possible, i need the result of controller 2 in order to execute next lines of controller 1.

Comment: sorry i didn't; get you. Please talk in context of above code

Comment: @ShashankShetti I have updated execution process, fix few bit according to your needs and let me know it works

Comment: what i told was 1st line is in one controller and remaining below code is in another controller, if i have to use await in 1st controller, i have to put async before that

Comment: this one is also not working, whats happening here is, upto "const err = await invoiceItem.save();" this line code executes number of times the length of the array normally, but after that it will jump into " return  resposneArray;" line and comes back to controller one without executing the save querry.

Comment: that means returned responseArray is still an empty array, now in controller one the remaining code below will be executed, after executing the remaing code in controller one, it will again comes back to controller two and executes the save() querry and executes the code inside the "await invoiceItem.save();" which is useless because all the code in controller one is already executed.

Comment: @ShashankShetti did you debug `await invoiceItem.save()` method. What it is doing. It should also be implemented as async/await (Promise)

Comment: I mean did you jump into that method and seen through what it is trying to and flow of execution?

Comment: ya it will come to await invoiceItem.save(), but not at the right time, it comes back to controller 1, executes the remaining code and after completing the execution in controller 1 it comes back to controller 2 and executes await invoiceItem.save(),  but i need save the invoice Items before it has to come to controller 1, so that if the invoice items saved only without any errors, i need to  execute the remaining further codes of controller 1, so as the invoice items are saved yet how can i further executes the codes in controller 1.

Comment: @ShashankShetti I think problem is with using foreach which expect the sync calls and it does not guarantee the execution sequence. So I have updated solution to use native `for.. of` loop. Check that and let me know

Comment: thank god it worked bro, thank you for the assistance. But i have another challenge i will post it as separate question.

Comment: @ShashankShetti cool... Could you also upvote this answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: ya i upvoted, but its not taking, i have another challenge could you please suggest a solution to it.

Comment: sure, i will try

Answer (score 0):

You should use async await while writing to db.

```
  var invoiceItemResp = await InvoiceItemController.createInvoiceItems(itemList, doc.id);

 exports.createInvoiceItems = async (itemList, invoiceId) => {
    var counter = 0;
    var success = false;
    itemList.forEach(element => {
        var invoiceItem = new InvoiceItem({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            invoice_id: invoiceId,
            item: element.item,
            amount: element.amount
        });
        invoiceItem.save((err, doc) => {
            if(!err){
                ++counter;
                if(counter == itemList.length){
                    response = {
                        "message": "success"
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            }else{
                response = {
                    "message": "failed"
                }
                return response;
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: if we use await in line 1, we have to add async in that controller because await will not work without async, if i add async also, another problem is if i add await in line 1 it come out of second controller(from line 2) before executing invoice.save(), after executing remaining lines in controller 1, it will go back to controller 2 to execute invoiceItem.save(), how it is possible, i need the result of controller 2 in order to execute next lines of controller 1.